# Control reaches at the end of non-void function

Tags: c++

I am doing a question on Hackerrank ,but whenever I compile my code it shows control reaches at  the end of non-void function .Here is my source code :

```
   /*
Compare two linked lists A and B
Return 1 if they are identical and 0 if they are not. 
Node is defined as 
struct Node
{
 int data;
 struct Node *next;
}
*/
int CompareLists(Node *headA, Node* headB)
{

if(headA==NULL&&headB==NULL)
 {
   return 1;
 }
 else if( headA!=NULL&&headB!=NULL)
 {
   while(headA!=NULL&&headB!=NULL)
    {
       if(headA->data==headB->data)
           {
           headA=headA->next;
           headB=headB->next;
             }
       else
           {
           return 0;
           exit (0);
       }
       return 1;
   }
}
else
    {
    return 0;
}
}
```

Please tell how to rectify this and thanks in advance.

Comment: It might help you to see what's going wrong if you fix the indentation.

Answer (score 3):

I can see two problems with reachability here.  First the simple one:

```
  {
      return 0;
      exit (0);
  }
```

The `exit` call is unreachable.  (That line is almost certainly a mistake.  I can't think of any good reason to call `exit` there.)

Next the more complicated one ... that is the root cause of the compilation error:

```
while(headA!=NULL&&headB!=NULL)
    {
       if(headA->data==headB->data)
           {
           headA=headA->next;
           headB=headB->next;
             }
       else
           {
           return 0;
           exit (0);
       }
       return 1;
   }
```

Look at where the `return 1;` is.  It is INSIDE the loop.

So, what happens if `headA != NULL && headB != NULL` evaluates to false?  In that case, the loop body with the `return 1;` at the end is skipped ... and you reach the end of the method.

Hence the compilation error.

I suspect that the "fix" is to move the `return` to after the loop, but I didn't try to understand the logic of your code, so that might be the wrong "fix".

Answer (score 0):

What happens after this code executes?

```
if(headA->data==headB->data)
{
     headA=headA->next;
     headB=headB->next;
}
```

...if `headA->next == NULL` or `headB->next == NULL`?